# Can't import Scapy arping() method

Tags: python, scapy, arp

```
from scapy.layers.l2 import arping
from scapy.all import *

def scan(ip):
    scapy.layers.l2.arping(ip)

scan('192.168.0.1')
```

Can someone explain why those imports need to look like this?

I saw in a tutorial that for the guy was enough to "import scapy.all as scapy" and he had that arping() method working fine.

When I delete "from scapy.all import *" the reference in scan function to scapy is gone. Shouldn't it be gone if I'm importing this "scapy.layers.l2..."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import as you have there, you'd use the name `arping` directly:

```
from scapy.layers.l2 import arping

def scan(ip):
    arping(ip)
```

If you imported as they had, you'd do this:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def scan(ip):
    scapy.arping(ip)
```