# Cannot find reference 'arping' in 'all.py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, wifi, scapy

I am trying to run this code and not able to due to error in the last line. I added line 4 from various answers found here. But still not able to get an output.

I get these problems on Pycharm Community 2022.3.2

[image]

The same even when I use Text Editor or VSCode on Ubuntu 22.04

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Import scapy

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy.layers.l2 import ARP, Ether

# We need to create regular expressions to ensure that the input is correctly formatted.
import re

# Basic user interface header

print('Hello, We are on!!')



# Regular Expression Pattern to recognise IPv4 addresses.
ip_add_range_pattern = re.compile("^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/[0-9]*$")

# Get the address range to ARP
while True:
    ip_add_range_entered = input("\nPlease enter the ip address and range that you want to send the ARP request to (ex 192.168.1.0/24): ")
    if ip_add_range_pattern.search(ip_add_range_entered):
        print(f"{ip_add_range_entered} is a valid ip address range")
        break


# Try ARPing the ip address range supplied by the user.
# The arping() method in scapy creates a pakcet with an ARP message
# and sends it to the broadcast mac address ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff.
# If a valid ip address range was supplied the program will return
# the list of all results.
arp_result = scapy.arping(ip_add_range_entered)
```

I tried installing `arping` using `sudo apt install arping`, without luck.

Added line 4 from different answers available here

I installed full Scapy using `pip install --pre scapy[complete]`, no luck.

Hope to get a list of device connected to my network. Ultimate aim to log them and get and alert when there is a new device on the network.

Thanks.

Edit 1:

Everything goes fine until I enter the IP properly. It even suggests wrong entry if I make a mistake. Once I enter the right IP range, it says, it is a valid IP range and then throws error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/computerw/PycharmProjects/desk-app-QT/main.py", line 37, in <module>
    arp_result = scapy.arping(ip_add_range_entered)
  File "/home/computerw/PycharmProjects/desk-app-QT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 890, in arping
    ans, unans = srp(
  File "/home/computerw/PycharmProjects/desk-app-QT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 687, in srp
    s = iface.l2socket()(promisc=promisc, iface=iface,
  File "/home/computerw/PycharmProjects/desk-app-QT/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scapy/arch/linux.py", line 484, in __init__
    self.ins = socket.socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 232, in __init__
    _socket.socket.__init__(self, family, type, proto, fileno)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import Scapy arping() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69828422/cant-import-scapy-arping-method)

Comment: Just tried both ways, no luck. Thanks.

Comment: `arping()` resides in `scapy.layers.l2`. So, you need to modify your import statement at the top to include `arping`, then down at the bottom just call `arping(...`, not `scapy.arping(...`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that now. But it still fails. Please see : https://imgur.com/y1QxV5V

Comment: I would ask this as a new question. Include your corrected code and your input, along with the full text of the traceback. Unfortunately, 1) I'm not on Linux ATM, and 2) I'm not a networking specialist, so you def want to reach a wider audience than me :)

Comment: `PermissionError` is raised because `arping` requires administrator privileges (a non administrator user cannot send anything he/she wants on the network).  On linux this means you need to launch your script as root.